# How to convert the code to use CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, java-8

I used to have a callable class

```
class SampleTask implements Callable<Double> {
  @Override
  public Double call() throws Exception {
    return 0d;
  }
}
```

I used to use `ExecutorService` to submit the `Callable`. How to change to use `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync`?

The following code cannot compile

```
SampleTask task = new SampleTask();
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(task);
```

> No instance of type of variable U exists so that SampleTask conforms to Supplier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`supplyAsync()` expects a `Supplier<U>` and you are giving it a `Callable`.

The error message is telling you that the compiler has tried to find a type to use for `U` such that your `SampleTask` "is a" `Supplier<U>`, but it can't find one.

Java will implicitly "promote" a lambda to a functional interface such as `Callable` or `Supplier`. But it won't treat functional interfaces as interchangeable -- that is, you can't use a `Callable` where a `Supplier` is expected.

You can make a suitable lambda in-place:

```
SimpleTask task = new SimpleTask();
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> task.call());
```

Note that this works if `SimpleTask`'s `call()` is:

```
 public Double call() {  // note no exception declared
    return 0d;   
 }
```

The fact that `SimpleTask` happens to implement `Callable` is not relevant to the code above.

---

If you want this to work with an arbitrary `Callable`, or if you declare `task` as a `Callable`:

```
Callable callable = new SimpleTask();
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> callable.call());
```

... then you will get a compiler error about the uncaught exception. Your lambda will need to catch the exception and handle it (perhaps rethrowing as an unchecked exception, as described in other answers).

---

Or you could make `SampleTask` implement `Supplier<Double>`.

---

Part of the motivation for lambdas is that writing things like `Callable` was too verbose. So you might well leave out the intermediate class and go directly for:

```
CompleteableFuture<Double> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 0d);
```

This applies for more complicated suppliers too:

```
CompleteableFuture<Double> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
     Foo foo = slowQuery();
     return transformToDouble(foo);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

For your callable as written, you could simply use `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 0d);`.

If, however, you have an existing `Callable`, using it with `CompletableFuture` is not so straight-forward due to the checked exceptions that a callable might throw.

You may use an ad-hoc `Supplier` which catches exceptions and re-throws it wrapped in an unchecked exception like

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    try { return callable.call(); }
    catch(Exception e) { throw new CompletionException(e); }
})
```

Using the specific type `CompletionException` instead of an arbitrary subtype of `RuntimeException` avoids getting a `CompletionException` wrapping a runtime exception wrapping the actual exception when calling `join()`.

Still, you’ll notice the wrapping when chaining an exception handler to the `CompletableFuture`. Also, the `CompletionException` thrown by `join()` will be the one created in the `catch` clause, hence contain the stack trace of some background thread rather than the thread calling `join()`. In other words, the behavior still differs from a `Supplier` that throws an exception.

Using the slightly more complicated

```
public static <R> CompletableFuture<R> callAsync(Callable<R> callable) {
    CompletableFuture<R> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try { cf.complete(callable.call()); }
        catch(Throwable ex) { cf.completeExceptionally(ex); }
    });
    return cf;
}
```

you get a `CompletableFuture` which behaves exactly like `supplyAsync`, without additional wrapper exception types, i.e. if you use

```
callAsync(task).exceptionally(t -> {
    t.printStackTrace();
    return 42.0;
})
```

`t` will be the exact exception thrown by the `Callable`, if any, even if it is a checked exception. Also `callAsync(task).join()` would produce a `CompletionException` with a stack trace of the caller of `join()` directly wrapping the exception thrown by the `Callable` in the exceptional case, exactly like with the `Supplier` or like with `runAsync`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `CompleteableFuture::supplyAsync` expects a `Supplier<Double>` and not `Callable<Double>` you should go with:

```
Callable<Double> task = new SampleTask();
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
  try {
    return task.call();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
});
```

Comment: Even though `call` declares that it throws `Exception`, the compiler doesn't need the `try/catch` so it's only needed if you know that `call` could throw.

Comment: @slim: as long as the declared type of `task` is `Callable`, you need the `try…catch`, even if you know that it won’t throw. Even if you change it to `SampleTask`, you’ll need it as long as its implementation method also declares to `throws Exception`.

Comment: @Holger you're right. Will restate as *if the type of `task` is `SampleTask` (even when `SampleTask implements Callable`) and `SampleTask.call()` doesn't declare an exception* then the `catch` is not required.

Answer (score 0):

I had this come up recently and used Vavr to solve it (was already using it for other things, too), and it worked out great for me:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> Try.ofCallable( callable ).get() )
```

Or to get a Supplier of that CompletableFuture:

```
() -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> Try.ofCallable( callable ).get() )
```

In all cases I tested this returned exactly and threw exactly what the callable itself did.