# CompletableFuture#exceptionally rethrow checked exception

Tags: java, exception, java-8, completable-future

Suppose I want to recover with some value if I get a specific exception, otherwise return the failed future with the exception. I would expect something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(FuturesExample::fetchValue)
            .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                if (throwable instanceof RuntimeException) {
                    return "All good";
                }
                throw throwable; // does not compile
            });
}

public static String fetchValue() {
    // code that potentially throws an exception
    return "value";
}
```

If the `fetchValue` function would throw a *checked* exception, I would like to handle it in the chained methods. I have tried both `return throwable` and `throw throwable`, but neither does compile. Do `CompletableFuture`s offer any solution to this scenario? I am aware that the `Function` interface that is the parameter of the `exceptionally` method does not throw any exceptions - I would just like to return the already failed future in this case. I would like to find a solution using Java 8.

Comment: Class `CompletableFuture` was first added in JDK 8 but was enhanced in JDK 9. I think that in order to provide you an appropriate answer, you need to indicate which JDK you are using.

Comment: Java 8 - I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: CompletableFuture.exceptionally is defined as returning a CompletableFuture, neither a String nor an exception (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html). This cannot compile.

Comment: @UweAllner You are wrong. `exceptionally(throwable -> "value")` is perfectly valid and works as expected. The function still returns `CompletableFuture`, the lambda is a parameter.

Answer (score 11):

In this scenario, it is impossible to receive a checked exception as the previous stage is based on a `Supplier`, which is not allowed to throw checked exceptions.

So you could handle all unchecked exceptions and raise an `AssertionError` for the throwables that ought to be impossible:

```
CompletableFuture
    .supplyAsync(FuturesExample::fetchValue)
    .exceptionally(throwable -> {
        if (throwable instanceof RuntimeException) {
            return "All good";
        }
        if(throwable instanceof Error) throw (Error)throwable;
        throw new AssertionError(throwable);
    });
```

Otherwise, you may consider that subsequent stages, as well as callers of `join()` will get all exceptions except `CompletionException` and `CancellationException` wrapped in a `CompletionException` anyway. E.g. when I use

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompletableFuture<String> f = CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(FuturesExample::fetchValue)
        .exceptionally(throwable -> {
            if(throwable instanceof RuntimeException) {
                throw (RuntimeException)throwable;
            }
            throw new Error();
        });
    f.whenComplete((s,t) -> {
        if(t != null) {
            System.err.println("in whenComplete handler ");
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    System.err.println("calling join()");
    f.join();
}
public static String fetchValue() {
    throw new IllegalStateException("a test is going on");
}
```

I get

```
in whenComplete handler 
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: a test is going on
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1692)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: a test is going on
    at FuturesExample.fetchValue(FuturesExample.java:23)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    ... 6 more
calling join()
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: a test is going on
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1692)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: a test is going on
    at FuturesExample.fetchValue(FuturesExample.java:23)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    ... 6 more
```

So I can use `CompletionException` for wrapping arbitrary throwables, utilizing the fact that `CompletionException` does not get wrapped again. So if I use

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompletableFuture<String> f = CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(FuturesExample::fetchValue)
        .exceptionally(throwable -> {
            if(throwable instanceof CompletionException)
                throwable = throwable.getCause();
            System.err.println("wrapping '"+throwable+"' inside exceptionally");
            throw new CompletionException(throwable);
        });
    f.whenComplete((s,t) -> {
        if(t != null) {
            System.err.println("in whenComplete handler ");
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    System.err.println("calling join()");
    f.join();
}
public static String fetchValue() {
    throw new IllegalStateException("a test is going on");
}
```

I get

```
wrapping 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: a test is going on' inside exceptionally
in whenComplete handler 
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: a test is going on
    at FuturesExample.lambda$main$0(FuturesExample.java:12)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:986)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:970)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.unipush(CompletableFuture.java:589)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionallyStage(CompletableFuture.java:1002)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.exceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2307)
    at FuturesExample.main(FuturesExample.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: a test is going on
    at FuturesExample.fetchValue(FuturesExample.java:24)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1692)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177)
calling join()
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: a test is going on
    at FuturesExample.lambda$main$0(FuturesExample.java:12)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:986)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:970)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.unipush(CompletableFuture.java:589)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionallyStage(CompletableFuture.java:1002)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.exceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2307)
    at FuturesExample.main(FuturesExample.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: a test is going on
    at FuturesExample.fetchValue(FuturesExample.java:24)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1692)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177)
```

which differs slightly in the stack traces, but does not make a difference to the code receiving/catching the exception, as in either case, it’s a `CompletionException` wrapping an `IllegalStateException`.

So going back to the example of your question, you could use

```
CompletableFuture
    .supplyAsync(FuturesExample::fetchValue)
    .exceptionally(throwable -> {
        if (throwable instanceof RuntimeException) { // includes CompletionException
            return "All good";
        }
        throw new CompletionException(throwable);
    });
```

Since `CompletionException` is a `RuntimeException`, this code handles it and avoids wrapping a `CompletionException` in another `CompletionException`. Otherwise, the pattern would be

```
    .exceptionally(throwable -> {
        if (some condition) {
            return some value;
        }
        throw throwable instanceof CompletionException?
            (CompletionException)throwable: new CompletionException(throwable);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So basically there's no other way than wrapping the exception with an unchecked one and then handling it accordingly in the `exceptionally` clause and then accessing `Throwable#getCause`?

Comment: A `CompletableFuture` can get completed by calling `completeExceptionally` with an arbitrary `Throwable`, so does the solution in the middle of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43767613/2711488) for using a `Callable` work. However, for most cases, it’s an unnecessary complication, given that for subsequent consumers or when calling `join()`, you’ll get that throwable wrapped in a `CompletionException` anyway.

Answer (score 3):

As [holger wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55476548/6537157), this is normally not possible.
But, there is a trick with lombok and it's [@SneakyThrows](https://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows).

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(FuturesExample::fetchValue)
            .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                if (throwable instanceof RuntimeException) {
                    return "All good";
                }
                FutureExample.reThrow(throwable);
                // maybe a "return null" is necessary here (even when it is not reachable)
            });
}

public static String fetchValue() {
    // code that potentially throws an exception
    return "value";
}

@SneakyThrows // <- threat checked exceptions in method-body as unchecked
public static void reThrow(Throwable throwable) {
   throw throwable;
}
```

---

You can also archive it with `ExceptionUtils.rethrow()` (thanks [vlp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5128464/vlp)).

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(FuturesExample::fetchValue)
            .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                if (throwable instanceof RuntimeException) {
                    return "All good";
                }
               reThrow(throwable);
                // maybe a "return null" is necessary here (even when it is not reachable)
            });
}
```

Comment: An alternative to lombok is `ExceptionUtils.rethrow()` from commons lang3.

Comment: a nicer syntax for rethrow is `throw (RuntimeException)ExceptionUtils.rethrow(ex);` (note that the invalid cast is never executed). This way it is much more obvious where the code path ends.